# space symbol in html implementation

Tags: html

I want to indent text with several spaces. So I need to put some spaces before the text in order to indent the text. Obviously `&#32;` doesn't work. Is there another symbol that would do that for me. I don't use CSS. Just in a plain html.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `&nbps;` represents a single space, multiple of them will represent multiple spaces. `<pre></pre>` also works by telling HTML to allow formatting

Comment: &nbsp;.. 1 second too late

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a *non-breaking* space, it is designed for use between words where you don't want a word break (e.g. in the middle of names). It is not designed to be used as a hack to replace CSS. **If you want to do typography, use CSS, that's the tool designed to do it**

Comment: @Quentin did you downvote our answers. Did you not read OP question, `Just in plain html`

Comment: I upvotet you back.. he surely didn't read.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be *the right way* by some peoples standards, but following the OP:

> Just in a plain html

`&nbps;` represents a single space, multiple of them will represent multiple spaces. [Html Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

`<pre></pre>` also works by telling HTML to allow formatting, [preformatted text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bwe3u2t/)

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple times this combination in your html code:

```
&nbsp;

<p>This &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; will be spaced</p>
```